# Wikitude Camera doesn't prompted in ios

Tags: ios, camera, wikitude

I'm facing a critical issue about opening `wikitude camera` in ios although `wikitude` is running. Any of my code did wrong to open wikitude camera? Please help and thanks.

This is my `CameraPlugin.h` :

```
#import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h`<br>
#import Cordova/CDV.h

 @interface CameraPlugin : CDVPlugin

 - (void)launchCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

 @end
```

This is my `CameraPlugin.m`  :

```
#import "CameraPlugin.h"<br>
#import "CDVMainViewController.h"<br>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h><br>
#import <WikitudeSDK/WikitudeSDK.h><br>

     @interface CameraPlugin() <WTArchitectViewDelegate><br>
     @property (nonatomic, strong) WTArchitectView  *architectView;<br>
     @property (nonatomic, assign) WTNavigation     *architectWorldNavigation;<br>
     @property (nonatomic, strong) CDVMainViewController *view;<br>
     @end

     @implementation CameraPlugin

     -(void) dealloc {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];}

     -(void)launchCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
        NSError *deviceSupportError=nil;

        if([WTArchitectView isDeviceSupportedForRequiredFeatures:WTFeature_2DTracking error:&deviceSupportError]) {
        NSLog(@"Device is supported Wikitude SDK");

        self.view = [[CDVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        NSLog(@"=== View is configure ===");
        self.architectView = [[WTArchitectView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero motionManager:nil];
        self.architectView.delegate = self;

        NSLog(@"=== LicenseKey is configure ===");
        [self.architectView setLicenseKey:@""];

        NSLog(@"=== URL loading ===");
        self.architectWorldNavigation = [self.architectView loadArchitectWorldFromURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"ArchitectWorld"] withRequiredFeatures:WTFeature_2DTracking];

        NSLog(@"architectWorldNavigation : %@", self.architectWorldNavigation);

        NSLog(@"Observer is configure");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:) name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];`


        NSLog(@"Subview is configure");
        [self.view.view addSubview:self.architectView];
        self.architectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
           NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_architectView);
        [self.view.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_architectView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views] ];
        [self.view.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_architectView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views] ];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.view.view);

        NSLog(@"Result is configure");

       [self startWikitudeSDKRendering];

        NSLog(@"Wikitude is Running - %d", [self.architectView isRunning]);

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"true"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"This device is not supported. Show either an alert or use this class method even before presenting the view controller that manages the WTArchitectView. Error: %@", [deviceSupportError localizedDescription]);

       pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"true"];
    }

   `[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];`
}

   `- (void)startWikitudeSDKRendering {`<br>
     `NSLog(@"Wikitude is Running - %d", [self.architectView isRunning]);`<br>
    `if ( ![self.architectView isRunning] ) {`<br>
        `NSLog(@"Try to start wikitude sdk");`<br>
        `[self.architectView start:^(WTStartupConfiguration *configuration{`
            `// configuration.captureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;`

        } completion:^(BOOL isRunning, NSError *error) {

           /* The completion block is called right after the internal start method returns.

             NOTE: In case some requirements are not given, the WTArchitectView might not be started and returns NO for isRunning.
             To determine what caused the problem, the localized error description can be used.
             */
            if ( !isRunning ) {
                NSLog(@"WTArchitectView could not be started. Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }
}

    `- (void)stopWikitudeSDKRendering {
    if ( [self.architectView isRunning] ) {
        [self.architectView stop];
    }
}`
 `@end`
```

Here is my logcat (Wikitude service seems running but there is not camera prompted):

> 2016-04-25 18:02:13.330 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Device is supported Wikitude SDK
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.341 CPBVOCA[357:30022] === View is configure ===
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.380 CPBVOCA[357:30022] === LicenseKey is configure ===
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.381 CPBVOCA[357:30022] === URL loading ===
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.389 CPBVOCA[357:30022] architectWorldNavigation : navigation: original URL: 'file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/9A01A65D-34A9-4AB2-B733-A8C5CE9B40F9/CPBVOCA.app/ArchitectWorld/index.html' - final URL: '(null)' - isLoading: '1' - wasInterrupted: '0'
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.389 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Observer is configure
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.389 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Subview is configure
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.435 CPBVOCA[357:30022] UIView: 0x141425e70; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x13ff76680
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.436 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Result is configure
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.436 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Wikitude is Running - 0
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.436 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Try to start wikitude sdk
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.708 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Wikitude is Running - 1
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.710 CPBVOCA[357:30022] THREAD WARNING: ['CameraPlugin'] took '404.823975' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
>   2016-04-25 18:02:13.712 CPBVOCA[357:30022] Success to get camera plugin

Comment: Did you considered using the default Wikitude Cordova plugin?

Comment: why did you wrote `self.view = [[CDVMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`? Assigning a view controller to a view seems odd to me.